# webpack copy folder without processing of scripts

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am writing a very small web component and all I need is for webpack to copy a folder from my root to the `dist`. I don't really want it to process any of my JavaScript or CSS.

So I created the following `webpack.config.js` file:

```
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');    
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        { from: 'fontawesome', to: 'dist' },
      ],
    }),
  ],
};
```

However it tells me :

```
ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in 'D:\Examples\sdk-icon'
```

But as stated above I don't want it to process my JavaScript - so how can I just make it copy ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to copy files within you project folder you better npm module for that.

[For example this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copyfiles).

Add command to package.json scripts section and execute it when you need.

Comment: How would that command look like i tried copyfiles /fontawesome/* /dist/ but that did nothing

Comment: try copyfiles ./fontawesome/* ./dist/

Comment: but this will create fontawesome folder in dist folder
to avoid this you just need to add -f arg
so final command will look like that
copyfiles -f ./fontawesome/* ./dist/

and double check if source folder is correct

Comment: I've created a repo with example.

https://github.com/AntonBakinowsky/copyfilestest

Comment: i dont know what the difference was but now it works thank you